# access session by subdomains

Tags: php, html, session, subdomain

hello i have a problem with accessing a session on a subdomain. the session will be set on domain.com by using this code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
ini_set("session.cookie_domain",".domain.com");
session_start();
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
....
```

so adding a point in front of the domain should probably set the session even for subdomain.

i had a look at the phpinfo wwhere i found this line:

```
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
```

because of the hosters setting i have no chance to edit the php.ini file. so i had to add the ini_set line on all files like above.

the problem is the following: when i will call domain.com a session will be set. i built a testpage that easily echo out the session and cookie. as i said the session will be set on domain.com and when i will call domain.com/testfile.php it will be shown correctly. but when i will call www.domain.com/testfile.php just the cookie will be displayed but not the session, that is empty. there is also added the ini_set line on testfile.php.

so i have no clue why this doesnt work? i also deleted the cache and browser history several times but doesnt changed anything. i also tried differnt browsers.

if there is someone who could give me hints i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to start session first. then it will work

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
ini_set("session.cookie_domain",".domain.com");
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the follow options:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

In your .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

As the first thing in your script:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

or

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'example.com', false, false);
```

Or

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
            session_id($_COOKIE['session_id']);
        Zend_Session::start(); //or session_start();
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
            setcookie('session_id', session_id(), 0, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```